# How to proxy into another database user in Oracle database link, with kerberised authentication

Tags: oracle, kerberos, sqlplus, database-schema, database-link

Background:

2 Database hosts(with users): DB1(UserA), DB2(UserA, UserB)

A database link from **DB1**, **UserA**, created and works fine with the following SQL

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK "DB_LINK"
   USING '(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <DB2'S HOSTNAME>)(PORT = <PORT#>))
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = <DB2'S NAME>)
)
)';
```

and it is connectioned to **DB2, UserA**, they are the same account.

But in my case, i want to proxy into another DB user(**UserB**) in the above database link, tried some suggestion on Internet, which works but needs User_b's password.

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK "DB_LINK"
   CONNECT TO UserB IDENTIFIED by <pw>
   USING '(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <DB2'S HOSTNAME>)(PORT = <PORT#>))
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = <DB2'S NAME>)
)
)';
```

But in our case the we want the connection to be using Kerberos authentication, so we tried another suggestion to connect **via UserA**, and user bracket to proxy into UserB, by in here we dont have User_A's password as it is kerberised, and we use credential cache to make the connection. So, we dont have UserA's pw.

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK "DB_LINK"
   CONNECT TO UserA[UserB] IDENTIFIED by <UserA's pw>
   USING '(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <DB2'S HOSTNAME>)(PORT = <PORT#>))
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = <DB2'S NAME>)
)
)';
```

How to Connect to UserB, without specifying any passwords?

Also, permission have been granted

```
ALTER USER UserB GRANT CONNECT THROUGH UserA;
```